# Google Maps API filtro 'title'

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Boa noite,

Crio os marcadores no mapa utilizando o método:

```
    function addMarkersLabel() {
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (var i in points) {
            var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                position: points[i].latLng,
                title: points[i].titulo,
                icon: points[i].icone,
                zIndex: points.length - Number(i),
                map: GMaps,
                labelContent: points[i].labelContent,
                labelAnchor: points[i].labelAnchor,
                labelClass: points[i].labelClass
            });

            addMarkerListener(marker, points[i].id);
            markers.push(marker);
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
        }
    }
```

Porém preciso permitir depois que o mapa está criado exibir/ocultar os marcadores, utilizando como filtro o campo title do markers, se o 'title' for igual a X, exibo, senão oculto.

Comment: Dentro da sua variável "markers", você tem todos os objetos de _marker_, ou seja, faça uma iteração sobre esse Array "markers" e verifique a propriedade _title_ de cada um. Se sua condição for verdadeira, logo, faça alguma coisa, se não, faça outra coisa.

Comment: Mas qual o comando para acessar a propriedade 'title'?                     
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var marker = markers[i];
                                }

Comment: Debugue seu código, veja o que tem dentro de `markers[i]`, pois eu não sei como esse método cria o objeto. Talvez até seja `markers[i].title`, mas não tenho certeza, por isso o melhor a fazer é debugar o código. Utilize o `console.log()` e veja o que retorna no _Console_ do navegador.